# How to get unique array of hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to get unique array of hashes but I don't have any idea and have tried many ways. Please help me solve this:

**NOTE:** I don't want to use any Perl modules.

***What I tried:***

```
%seen=();
@unique = grep { ! $seen{$_} ++ } @AoH;
```

@unique is still not having unique hashes ??

FOR EXAMPLE:

**FROM:**

```
@AoH = (
{
   name  => "susheel",
   college => "MRITS",
},
{
   name  => "sunil",
   college => "MRITS",
},
{
   name  => "susheel",
   college => "MRITS",
},
);
```

**TO**

```
@AoH = (
{
   name  => "susheel",
   college => "MRITS",
},
{
   name  => "sunil",
   college => "MRITS",
}
);
```

Comment: Please don't write all-caps title.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - the three hashes in the first array are all different.  Why are there only two hashes in the second array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To filter hashes unique by `name` key,

```
my %seen;
my @unique = grep { ! $seen{$_->{name}}++ } @AoH;
```